# Taking the derivative of a function with indexed variables

Tags: core-language, differentials

I have a number of functions that depend on a variable `x`. I am using a second, integer variable to index these functions, i.e. something like

```
f[x_, 1] = a
f[x_, 2] = b x + c
```

When taking derivatives of these functions with `D`, it works the way I intend, i.e.

```
D[f[x, 1], x]
D[f[x, 2], x]
```

returns `0` respectively `b`. Now, however, I have a set of differential equations involving derivatives of these functions. These are expressed by *Mathematica* as

```
Derivative[1, 0][f][x, 1]
Derivative[1, 0][f][x, 2]
```

which remains unevaluated. Is there any way to have `Derivative` ignore the second variable? More specifically, I would like to have a way of doing something along the lines of

```
Derivative[1][g][x]
```

and then replacing `g` by `f[x, 1]`. I guess I could just assign specific names to each of the functions `f[x, k]`, but in the end I want to sum them all up

```
Sum[f[x, k],{k, 1, n}]
```

for which it would be convienient to have some index variable rather than writing out the sum over different functions. Maybe I am approaching the whole idea of indexing functions in the wrong way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can put the index in the first pair of brackets, and the variable in the second, like so:

```
f[1][x_] = a;
f[2][x_] := b x + c;
```

(Note that the second assignment uses [`SetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html) instead of [`Set`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html). This is necessary because the variable `x` occurs on the right-hand-side).

You can view `f[index]` as the function acting on `x`. The derivatives are computed as follows:

```
f[1]'[x]
```

> ```
> 0
> ```

```
f[2]'[x]
```

> ```
>  b
> ```

Computing the sum is then as easy as `Sum[f[k][x],{k,1,n}]`

Comment: +1 For currying.  Not a trick used often enough here, IMHO!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I did not know that using multiple levels of arguments was possible.