# Derivative of a function with indexed variables

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I want to show that
$$
\mathcal{U}(\mathbf x)=\prod_{i=1}^n U_i(x_i)
$$
is a concave function, where
$$
U_i(x_i)=\frac{c_i}{1+e^{b_i-a_i x_i}}+d_i
$$
and $a_i$, $b_i$, $c_i$, and $d_i$ are positive constants.

I define the following function in Mathematica

```
U[i][x_] := c[i]/(1 + Exp[-a[i] x + b[i]]) + d[i]
```

How can I take the second derivative of `Product[U[i][x[i]], {i, 1, n}]` then?
I tried

```
D[Product[U[i][x[i]], {i, 1, n}], x]
```

and

```
Assuming[j \[Element] Integers && j >= 1 && j <= n, D[Product[U[i][x[i]], {i, 1, n}], x]]
```

both of which produce `0` only!

[Here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/59506/taking-the-derivative-of-a-function-with-indexed-variables) is the most relevant question I found.

Comment: `D[Product[U[i][x[i]], {i, 1, n}], x[i]]`? Not that it evaluates, but the `Product[]` first doesn't evaluate.